# Memory address of a pointer

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I'm learning pointers, but I don't understand why this : `cout << pointer <<endl;` shows an address like this `0x171b20`. My computer is 64bits, so a pointer needs 16 Hexadecimal digits to fully identify a single memory address.

So I think that the c++ is only outputing a portion of the address ?

Can you please give me some explanations for that, and I also want to know how to get the full memory address of a pointer/variable ?

I'm using the mingw64 compiler.

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main()
{ 
    int *pointer; 
    pointer = new int; 
    cout << pointer << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: could you please share the piece of code where you print the pointer. Unless you use special format specifiers it will not print `0x`

Comment: ```#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
 int *pointer;
 pointer = new int;
 cout << pointer << endl;
 
 return 0;
}```

Comment: Okey, so that address `0x171b20` means `0x00171b20` ?

Comment: @MustaphaAJEGHRIR As you can see, code in a comment comes out looking terrible no matter how hard you try. This is by design because important stuff like the program code should be in the question. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63019949/edit) when you need to add information to a question.

Comment: @user4581301 Okey

Comment: @MustaphaAJEGHRIR "*Okey, so that address 0x171b20 means 0x00171b20*" - in 32bit, yes.  In 64bit, `0x171b20` is the same as `0x0000000000171b20`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cout << pointer << endl` will work to print out the full address of a pointer. However, the pointer does not **have** to have 8 non-zero bytes (16 hexadecimal digits). For example, in many programs, functions can have addresses like 0x0000000000401234, which will print out as 0x401234.

Comment: So if the program show 6 digits, that means that the rest is just zeros ?

Comment: Yes, it's like how 02 and 2 are the same number.

Comment: The formating actually seems compiler-dependent, i've just tried to `cout<<some_ptr` on VS2017, and it printed 16 hexadecimal digits on 64 bit build, and 8 hexadecimal digits on 32 bit build, without the 0x prefix, on it's own (without me controlling the formating in any way). But why would one really care about specific format of pointers printout? Why would anyone print them, other than some exotic debugging?

Comment: @BorisLipschitz teachers, TAs, and robo-markers can be weirdly specific.

Comment: @user4581301 nothing prevents you from spitting it out in any format you (or they) want.

Comment: @BorisLipschitz Yuppers. But it's a reason in addition to exotic debugging.